# Iteration (very basic question on terminology)

Tags: terminology, recursion

A finitary union of sets $\bigcup_{n=1}^{n} S_i \leftrightarrow S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \ldots S_n$ or a series such as $\sum_{n=1}^{n} 2^{-n} = 1$, they all represent the same generic operation of iterating terms connected by the same logical ($\cup)$ or mathematical ($+$) operator. I'd like to use the proper terminology that expresses this idea of repetition of terms a set amount of times. Is that some case of iteration or recursion or is the term iteration reserved to functions? And how do we technically refer to the upper and lower limits of such repetitions?

Comment: I've heard of an "$n$-fold" sum, but not an $n$-fold union of sets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)

Comment: Indeed, I know what a union is, I'm stating that I might use the terminology "n-fold" to describe a sum, but I would not similarly use it to describe an iterated union.

Comment: This could use a bit more context of when/where you would like to refer to this. For instance, I suspect that the generalization you allude to is familiar to most who do functional programming, but likely not worth naming for many mathematicians. So the question of a "proper term" for this depends on the audience you're addressing.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus, "$n$-fold union" sounds okay to me and also seems to be in use based on a quick Google search. For example, in these notes from 2010: https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.745/Notes/Lecture_7_Notes.pdf

Comment: @MarkS. Oh, I see... nevertheless, would it be acceptable to use the term iteration in a more generic sense to refer to these operations?

Comment: That sounds in line with the usage in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_binary_operation , yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on [the English Wikipedia page for "iterated binary operation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_binary_operation), "iteration" is indeed a generic term that can be used for this sort of thing.

More specific terms like $n$-fold union/sum are mentioned on that page as well.